# how the C read the character and Line break when i use loop?

Tags: c, character, line-breaks, getchar, putchar

When i try the loop, i find some doubts.

1. When i press "Enter" first time, it prints two blank lines, at the second time, it prints two more blank lines and execution following statement.
2. When i press "Enter" then "#", and "Enter" again it won't end.

I wonder why?

```
while((ch = getchar()) != '#')
{
    putchar(ch);
    while(getchar() != '\n')
            ;
    printf("\nEnter next word.");
}
```

i want to understand how it works.

Comment: Use a Debugger or a pencil and a piece of paper

Comment: The `getchar` function removes the character it reads from the input buffer, it can never be read again.

Comment: And remember that output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` and `putchar` writes) is by default *line buffered*, which means that the output will be buffered until you write a newline. Now think about how that works with your `printf` call, where you print a leading newline.

Comment: Oh and your code has a very fatal flaw: What if the user presses the end-of-file key sequence? `EOF != '#'` and `EOF != '\n'`. And while talking about `EOF`, I do hope your variable `ch` is an `int` since that's what [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns, and is actually very important for the `EOF` checks.

Comment: It does not print two blank lines. The first one is the blank line that you have inserted and the second one is the `putchar()`  blank line. Just like when you give a certain character it appears two times.

Comment: So you can ask me : " Why when I press space after the 'Enter next word' statement there is only one blank line?". It is because just as @Someprogrammerdude said the first blank line is inserted after your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I recommend using a debugger to step through this program. Seeing what is happening line by line is the best way to understand eveything that is happening and improve your coding skills.

That said it will help to have some knowledge of what `getchar` is doing by default when you have an interactive program on most systems. When you call `getchar` the first time it will in turn call a lower level operarating system function which will get input from the standard input (`stdin`). On linux for example the low level function is `read` which will get input from a terminal.

On most systems what will happen by default is that the low level function won't return until enter is pressed. Anything typed will also be echoed back to the terminal/console, so you will see what you are typing.

Once you press enter `getchar` will return the first character relating to what you typed. If you type more than one character, the your next call to `getchar` will return immediately with the next chatacter you typed. Note that on Linux when you hit enter, it will be like you typed `'\n'`, however on Windows line endings are different, so it will be like `'\r'` then `'\n'`.

So the reason you see 2 blank lines the first time you hit enter is because the first is being echoed back by your low level os function, then the second by your `putchar`. `getchar` is called again and your 3rd blank line comes from the echo. The fourth comes from your `printf`.

I will leave the second part for you to figure out on your own.

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer is awesome， it helped me a lot.

Comment: @Absolutelyrun, no problem, terminals can be quite confusing when you first start using them.